# C# Cplex setting parameters

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, mathematical-optimization, cplex

I am working on simple optimization problem. My model is working but it takes too much time as number of inputs increases.
I wrote my code in c# using CPLEX.

So, I want to stop it when MIPGAP=0.5 but I couldn't find how to do it.

How, where and what should I add to my code to stop it when it reaches 0.5 gap.

Thank you advance.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar way how you set the gap, you have TimeLimit in Param

```
    IloCplex solver(...);   //initialise the solver with the model
    ... //many other commands
    solver.setParam(IloCplex::Param::TimeLimit,timeout);//customised timeout
    solver.setParam(IloCplex::EpGap,data.m_epgap);  //uses customised epgap
    if(!solver.solve()) {
        //non found
        return 0;
        }
```

Comment: vincent İ added my code pls comment on it bcs i dont know where to add statements.
Thanks you

Comment: thank you again i did it as

cplex.SetParam(Cplex.DoubleParam.EpGap, 0.5); (this is for .net)

Comment: cplex.SetParam(Cplex.DoubleParam.TiLim , value_in_sec)